# How to attach a UIGestureRecognizer to the item view in icarousel swift code

Tags: ios, swift, uitapgesturerecognizer, icarousel

Can somebody help me with adding a double tap recognizer for the center image in icarousel? In the swift code below you can see that the recognizer is programmed but it reacts everywhere on the screen and not only on the center image. I think I have to connect the gesture to newView but I tried several things but nothing solved the problem. There are a lot of examples in Objective-C but is Swift it is hard to find a solution on the forums. Hope somebody can tell me how to code it right.

```
import UIKit

let image0 = UIImage(named: "Afrojack")
let image1 = UIImage(named: "Calvin Harris")
let image2 = UIImage(named: "Martin Garrix")

var imageArray = [image0, image1, image2]


class ViewController: UIViewController, iCarouselDataSource, iCarouselDelegate
{
var items: [Int] = []

@IBOutlet weak var carousel: iCarousel!

override func awakeFromNib()
{
    super.awakeFromNib()
    for i in 0...2
    {
        items.append(i)
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
    carousel.type = .CoverFlow2
}


//show message when screen is tapped twice
func message(){
    let alertView = UIAlertView(title: "Oops!", message: "Something happened...", delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
    alertView.show()
}


func numberOfItemsInCarousel(carousel: iCarousel!) -> Int
{
    return items.count
}


@objc func carousel(carousel: iCarousel!, viewForItemAtIndex index: Int, reusingView view: UIView!) -> UIView! {
    var newView = view
    var label: UILabel! = nil

    if newView == nil {
        //create new view

        //don't do anything specific to the index within
        //this `if (view == nil) {...}` statement because the view will be
        //recycled and used with other index values later
        newView = UIImageView(frame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200))
        //(newView as! UIImageView).image = UIImage(named: "page")
        newView.contentMode = .Center

        // set label properties
        label = UILabel(frame:newView.bounds)
        label.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        label.textAlignment = .Center
        label.font = label.font.fontWithSize(50)
        label.tag = 1
        newView.addSubview(label)
    }
    else
    {
        //get a reference to the label in the recycled view
        label = newView.viewWithTag(1) as! UILabel!
    }

    //set item label
    //remember to always set any properties of your carousel item
    //views outside of the `if (view == nil) {...}` check otherwise
    //you'll get weird issues with carousel item content appearing
    //in the wrong place in the carousel

    //label.text = "\(items[index])"

    (newView as! UIImageView).image = imageArray[items[index]]

    newView.userInteractionEnabled = true

    let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self , action: "message")
    tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 2
    newView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)

    return newView
}
}


func carousel(carousel: iCarousel!, valueForOption option: iCarouselOption, withDefault value: CGFloat) -> CGFloat
{

    if (option == .Spacing)
    {
        return value * 1.1
    }

    return value

}
```

Comment: So you want it only in the center point or it can be a double tap anywhere on the image ?

Comment: I want a double tab on the image (newView) that is in the middle of the coverflow. When the image is double tapped I am making a segue to another screen where I am using the number of the image that is tapped to show information that belongs to the image. Think that the code has to be placed in the if statement of the @obj fun carousel method like the label (which I do not use).

Comment: **SOLVED**
The code above is working like I would it see working! FabKremer, thanks for your patience and helping comments!!!

Comment: Glad it worked dude! You're welcome :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried putting this code below the `newView` initialization?

```
let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self , action: "message")
tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 2
newView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
```

You should also delete that gesture in the `viewDidLoad()`.

**EDIT**

You should place the recognizer **after** `newView` is 100% not nil, cause where it is now, `newView` can be `nil` (you have a `if newView == nil`)
So place below all the `if` statement. It should work then.

Comment: I have tried it but in the simulator the code is crashing.

Comment: The code is crashing on the line

newView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)

fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Think the newView dus not know the addGestureRecognizer command.

Comment: But it should. Have you put the cose **below** the newView initialization?

Comment: Below you can see the complete code that is crashing.

Comment: Could not place the code as a comment so I replaced my original code above in my question. When the simulator enters the screen with the views it is crashing. Could it be that the gesture is not working because of the gesture that is used for scrolling the pictures? Somewhere I read that it is not allowed to have two gestures active? I have used the swift example of nick lockwood / icarousel and in the icarousel.m file is also a UITapGestureRecognizer present. When I tap a picture that is not in the middle then this picture is moved to the middle.

Comment: thanks for your patience and help so far. I changed my code like you suggest. See the code in my question above. Now the code does not crash and it could be that the tap is recognized. However nothing is happening when I double tap. I really feel like a silly guy and I am programming Siemens plc's every day.... Change in language could be the problem for me. Maybe because I am a newbe in Swift.